# A good book on Fractional Sobolev space.

Tags: sobolev-spaces, reference-works

Does someone can give me a good reference for fractional Sobolev spaces ? I looked on the internet but I didn't find any course on this subject. The only reference I found is the book of Adams, but it's much to complicate for beginners. So if someone could recommand me a good introduction course or book, it would be great.

Comment: An entire book on fractional order sobolev spaces will for sure be very advanced, it's not the first thing one learns about sobolev spaces, so it's obvious that, being an advanced topic, you will find it in advanced textbook. I don't remember distinctly, but I think Ziemer weakly differentiable function is a readable source. There are also some lecture notes by Giorgio Talenti where fractional order s.s. are introduced, but I don't know where to find them online, I have a draft copy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a very nice survey paper by several authors available [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345). It is not a book, but I am sure you will find it valuable.

Comment: Very nice paper!

Comment: Yes, very nice :) (+1)